# Angular - Template updates when it shows just properties but doesn't update if there are functions in it

Tags: angular, function, templates, auto-update

In my angular project, template updates perfectly when properties of model change, if it shows model properties directly:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let Discount of Discounts">
    <td><button type="button" (click)="Edit(Discount)">Edit</button></td>
    <td>{{ Discount.enabled }}</td>
    <td>{{ Discount.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ Discount.type }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But template doesn't update if pipe or function are used:

```
<td>{{ fun1(Discount.enabled) }}</td>
<td>{{ Discount.name }}</td>
<td>{{ Discount.type | pipe1 }}</td>
```

fun1 or pipe1 are simple functions that just return a string.

```
fun1 (in: boolean) {
   if (in)
     return 'message1';
   else 
     return 'message2'; 
}
```

enabled and type are boolean.
I even use ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() after any change on model properties. But it doesn't work. What is the problem? please help me.

I create this project on stackblitz. When boolean field such as "enabled" change from true to false, template does not update. But it works for false to true!

[stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vezupt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vezupt)

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with your issue ?

Comment: What Alexis said. There is not enough information here (for example, how are you changing the model..?)

Comment: I create this project. When boolean field such as "enabled" change from true to false, template does not update.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vezupt

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alexis and @MikeOne

Here your set `Discount.enabled` and `Discount.type` as boolean, But in your `DiscountEditComponent` return those properties as string like below one.

```
{
 enabled: 'false'
 id: 2
 name: "dis2"
 type: 'false'
}
```

I updated those attributes using `ngModelChange` when the `select` element has changed.

Ref: [Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jaqbwc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdiscount.service.ts)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, why DiscountEditComponent return those properties as string? I use property binding in template "option" tag. Is my code wrong?

Comment: ```option``` tag ```value``` attribute accepted as text/string type. So that, Your value has returned as as text/string.